# How to concatenate array of integers into comma separated string

Tags: powershell

I have two question, acually:

1. How to join array of integers into comma separated string? 
   *(1,2,3) => "1,2,3"*
2. How to convert array of integers to array of string? *(1,2,3) => ("1", "2", "3")*

```
$arraylist = New-Object 'system.collections.arraylist'
$arraylist.Add(1);
$arraylist.Add(2);

$csv = ?? 
#($arraylist-join -',') returns error: Cannot convert value "," to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your question, you've commented out the following snippet:

```
($arraylist-join -',')
```

because it returns the error `Cannot convert value "," to type "System.Int32"...`

The reason for this is the dash `-` in front of `','`.

In PowerShell, only *operators* and *parameters* are prefixed with a dash, and since `','` is neither (it's an *argument* to an operator), the PowerShell parser gets super confused and tries to treat `-','` as a value expression that would result in a negative number.

Just void the dash and you'll be fine:

```
$arraylist -join ','
```

---

Finally, you can easily cast an array of integers to an array of strings with the unchecked cast operator `-as` (PowerShell 3.0 and newer):

```
$StringArray = 1,2,3,4,5 -as [string[]]
```

or with an explicit cast (PowerShell 2.0-compatible):

```
$StringArray = [string[]]@(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
[String]::Join(",", $arraylist.ToArray())
```

I got `1,2`.

And then the second part:

```
foreach($number in $arraylist) { $number.ToString() }
```

Answer (score 2):

Next code snippet could help out on understanding:

```
$arraylist = New-Object 'system.collections.arraylist'
$arraylist.Add(111)           | Out-Null
$arraylist.Add([string]222)   | Out-Null
$arraylist.Add('"' + 3 + '"') | Out-Null
for($i=0; $i -lt $arraylist.Count; $i++ ){
    write-host $i, $arraylist[$i], $arraylist[$i].GetType()
}
write-host ''
$csv = $arraylist -join ','
$csv
```

**Output**:

```
0 111 System.Int32
1 222 System.String
2 "3" System.String

111,222,"3"
```

Additional view of (un)importance of `"` double quotes in a string type shows next `+` operation (sum of integers but concatenation of strings):

```
    write-host $i, $arraylist[$i], $arraylist[$i].GetType().Name, ($arraylist[$i] + 55)
```

gives next output:

```
0 111 Int32 166
1 222 String 22255
2 "3" String "3"55

111,222,"3"
```

However, `"` double quotes have another important and meaningful role in `.csv` file when imported e.g. to Excel sheet.

Answer (score -1):

I don't if this is correct. Usually, they have powershell2. Just give this a little try.

```
$a = @()
$strArrayNum=""
for($i=0; $i -lt $arraylist.length; $i++ ){
  $strArrayNum += $element
  $strArrayNum = $i+1 -eq $arraylist.length ? "" : ","
}

$a = $strArrayNum.Split(",")
```